# Selenium in Docker container, Can we take screen shot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker

I'm trying to execute selenium tests in Docker container (Linux Centos OS).
I've created three docker containers, one as hub & other two as node.
I'm trying to capture screen shot at a step. Didn't get any exception.
But I'm not able to find the screen shot (jpg file) on container.
I want to know if it is possible to take screen shot when running tests in docker container as test are run in headless mode?

Comment: What image are you using? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium? Double-check with http://www.conductor.com/nightlight/running-selenium-grid-using-docker-compose/

Comment: Where are you running the tests? Sounds like you are running the tests on the docker host so probably the images will end up there rather than in any of the containers. Could you post you code which takes the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is possible, but will require driver to support taking pictures in case of failure. 
One possibility is to use

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true)
```

But this to work require to be supported by driver(Ghost driver support this).

Comment: Every implementation apart from HtmlUnitDriver (alone?) supports varying level of screenshot, so it's incredibly unlikely that the OP has picked the one that doesn't. Besides, he said he didn't get any exceptions.